# Is there any modern interpretation for Indra's curse to women and other entities?

Tags: scripture, indra, interpretation, menstruation

Scriptures say that Indra killed Vishwroopa. It causes a Brahmahatya sin to Indra. Some entities then shared the guilt of Indra.

The following passage from Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam contains detailed list of curses

> Although Indra was so powerful that he could neutralize the sinful
> reactions for killing a brāhmaṇa, he repentantly accepted the burden
> of these reactions with folded hands. He suffered for one year, and
> then to purify himself he distributed the reactions for this sinful
> killing among the earth, water, trees and women. In return for King
> Indra’s benediction that ditches in the earth would be filled
> automatically, the land accepted one fourth of the sinful reactions
> for killing a brāhmaṇa. **Because of those sinful reactions, we find
> many deserts on the surface of the earth**. In return for Indra’s
> benediction that their branches and twigs would grow back when
> trimmed, the trees accepted one fourth of the reactions for killing a
> brāhmaṇa. **These reactions are visible in the flowing of sap from
> trees**. In return for Lord Indra’s benediction that they would be able
> to enjoy lusty desires continuously, even during pregnancy for as long
> as sex is not injurious to the embryo, women accepted one fourth of
> the sinful reactions. **As a result of those reactions, women manifest
> the signs of menstruation every month.** And in return for King Indra’s
> benediction that water would increase the volume of other substances
> with which it was mixed, water accepted one fourth of the sinful
> reactions. **Therefore there are bubbles and foam in water.** When one
> collects water, these should be avoided.
>
> [[6-10, 9, 6,  Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/9/)

Thus deserts on earth, flowing of sap in trees, menstruation in women and bubbles, foam in water are affected by Indra's sin.

Are there any modern scriptural interpretations for this story?

Comment: Those who are down-voted and closed, please provide a reason if possible. It is not an opinion based, it is a possible scriptural interpretation.

Comment: May be people think you want to do scientific speculation? Obviously not opinion based.

Comment: @Rickross yeah...

Answer (score 4):

Scriptures of Sanathan dharma do mention many astronomical, geographical facts etc.,  in a simple and cryptic way.

The story mentioned in this question encode several such facts.

One of the [meaning for Indra](https://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php?w=%E0%B0%87%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A6%E0%B1%8D%E0%B0%B0) is **sun /sun rays**.

Recent research is conforming those facts, but needs more research to understand those facts.

[Formation of deserts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert)

> Deserts are formed by weathering processes as large variations in
> temperature between day and night put strains on the rocks, which
> consequently break in pieces.

[On Menstrual cycle in women](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20937003/)

> Ovarian activity is greater in summer vs. winter in women living in a
> continental climate at temperate latitudes; sunshine is a factor that
> influences menstrual cycle.

[On sap flow in plants](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11632-007-0039-6)

> Results showed significant differences between changes in diurnal
> characteristics of , effective solar radiation and sap flow in sunny
> days during three seasons.... The start of sap flow was mainly induced
> by the sudden intensification of effective solar radiation.

You can notice the effect of sun on foam also and why it is should not be intaken. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foam_line#Biotic_and_abiotic_effects),[2](https://www.he-ss.si/eng/objava/what-causes-foam-to-appear-on-water-from-time-to-time-.html)

Although more research is needed to validate or understand the facts, the interpretation is scriptural. many stories in scriptures encode facts that occurs independent of time. The story may always happen.

The interpretation I provided is (inspired) by a Telugu preacher.

Comment: Even meaning of Indra in mistranslated  "Indra hit cow to a mountain. Go = Sun rays, Indra = Sun, "Sun rays permeate even hardest substances" verse in Vedas is Surya.. We should check Nirukta meanings for Vedic words.